# better had or had better. Which is correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

How does the first sentence differ from the second in the following sentences?

1) I had better zip my jacket up.

2) I better had zip my jacket up.

Comment: You **had better**.

Comment: @ user178049 why, not the second one?

Comment: It's an idiomatic and fixed expression. You cannot change it.

Comment: There are circumstances in which the idiom *better had* can be used, but this is not one of them. It is to create emphasis. Were you to say to me "I had better zip my jacket up", if it were a bitterly cold day I might reply *Yes, you better had*. Otherwise normally it would be alright to say *Yes, you had better*. Q *We are in a hurry, should we run?* A. *Yes, we had better* would just mean it would be advisable. However *Yes, we better had* might imply one's lives depended on it.

Comment: @WS2: It's true that when there are two ways of saying something, we often end up almost arbitrarily assigning some "less common meaning" to whatever seems to be the less common *phrasing*. But I've never been aware of anyone assigning ***additional emphasis*** to the very much less common sequence *Yes, we **better had** do that or else we'll die*. To me, it's just a *very* uncommon but insignificant "potentially optional inversion".

Comment: @FumbleFingers You may be right. It just seems to me to suggest greater urgency - but I've probably exaggerated the sense by using a life or death example.

Comment: @WS2: Equally, *you* may be right! My primary point is that the less common sequence is *very much* less common. So if it ever ***is*** used (in a context known to be from a competent speaker), we naturally tend to assume there's a *reason* for not using the more common form. And very often, the reason for using a "deviant" form is to draw attention / add emphasis. In short, to the extent this particular variation occurs at all, it's probably ***either*** "sloppiness" ***or*** a deliberate attempt to add emphasis. I'm just not familiar with the latter usage, is all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes. I can imagine a scenario in a company where, let's call him James is furious because he;s been left off an important list. He complains to the boss. The boss then speaks to the person who compiled the list, who realises the mistake and says "I'd better re-instate him". The boss replies **"you'd better had"** otherwise you'll get it in the neck from him.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted form is  *had better do ...* or *'d better do ...*:

> I had/I'd better zip my jacket up.

Sometimes, *had* is omitted:

> I better zip my jacket up.

Your second sentence sounds unnatural to my ear.

Please refer to [this answer on English Stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/236951/52777).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's "I had better".  But according to [*No Country For Old Men*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtfE1GWL4ig) (at 0:34), you could say it backwards to someone else...

> Waitress: Can I freshen that there for you Sheriff?
> Sheriff: Yeah, Maureen, you better had.

Comment: The Coen brothers love playing with language. The fact that some usage occurs in their movies doesn't necessarily imply that usage ever had *any* currency, but in this case there's no doubt that the inverted form ***You better had*** does in fact occur. But relatively speaking, it's extremely uncommon. My guess is the Coens knew perfectly well what thery were doing with that dialogue, where it's intended to imply a "folksy, idiosyncratic, rustic, frontier" context.

Comment: Note [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you+had+better%2Cyou+better+had&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20had%20better%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20better%20had%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cyou%20had%20better%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20better%20had%3B%2Cc0), where ***you better had*** is just a flat line underneath the standard version ***you had better***.

Comment: Yup, I think you're right.  I just checked McCarthy's book and that dialogue isn't there.  Also could have even been a Tommy Lee Jones mistake that got left in because it sounded so good.

Answer (score 0):

**You [I, we etc. )had better [do x]** is the expression.

**In response to someone saying that**, to emphasize the idea, it can be reversed:

Person 1: **We'd better leave right now**.
Person 2: Yes, **we better had**.

However, you cannot use "better had" the expression in the first sentence, it would not make sense.

Comment: " Yes, we better had" It means that we should have done it but we **didn't** ? I mean this is implying regret? Or the same as "had better" this is present?

Comment: @user48 Not regret: *We better had*. emphasizes *We had better do x*.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is grammatically correct.

We use **had better** to give advice, or tell people what to do. 'Had better' is similar to 'should'.

You had (You'd ) better go home.

We had (We'd) better hurry up.

You had (You'd) better be on time.

I had (I'd) better take an umbrella.

Negative (**had better not**)- You had (You'd) better not go.

You had (You'd) better not be late.

Sometimes we leave out 'had' in conversation.

You better go.

You can visit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eh8GS5bcfdk